# Should I always use "this" in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, this

Is it a good practice to use always 'this' in a method.
Even if there is no usage of the same variable name as input to this method.

```
String getStory(number) {
   return this.storyData[number];
}
```

By doing this there won't have any conflicts with any input variable name (never). 
Thank you in advance for your feedback.

Comment: Effective dart recommends only using `this` keyword when redirecting to a named constructor or to avoid shadowing. You can read more here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#dont-use-this-when-not-needed-to-avoid-shadowing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally `this.` is only supposed to be used when there is ambiguity about what variable is being used.

```
class Test{
  final int x;

  Test(this.x);
}
```